# How to prevent the popup password prompt when using GnuPG with mutt?

Tags: gnupg, mutt, popups

My mail user agent of choice is mutt, and I'm signing my mail using GnuPG.
To make them work together, I have `set crypt_use_gpgme=yes` in `.muttrc`.

Reading mail, I am asked to enter my OpenPGP key's passphrase, which is the expected behaviour. But instead of having to input it within the mutt prompt line, there is a GUI popup. This doesn't work without X, of course.

Is there a good way of *not* having this popup, but to enter the password within mutt, instead?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When used with `gpg-agent`, GnuPG uses a "pinentry" utility to query for the passphrase. There are different pinentry options; it seems you're using one of the graphical ones.

As an alternative, I'd propose you try out the two command line based pinentry options, one using curses, the other one plain comman line queries:

```
$ apt-cache search 'pinentry-(curses|tty)'
pinentry-curses - curses-based PIN or pass-phrase entry dialog for GnuPG
pinentry-tty - minimal dumb-terminal PIN or pass-phrase entry for GnuPG
```

They should also be available for non-Debian based distributions und similar names. After installing them, also configure `gpg-agent` to use them (from `man gpg-agent`):

> Please make sure that a proper `pinentry` program has been installed under the default filename (which is system dependent) or use the option `pinentry-program` to specify the full name of that program.  It is often useful to install a symbolic link from the actual used `pinentry` (e.g. `/usr/bin/pinentry-gtk`) to the expected one (e.g. `/usr/bin/pinentry`).

If you prefer the configuration file option, edit `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf`.

Comment: Thanks, I needed to be pointed in that direction ;)
In Archlinux, pinentry-curses is installed with the pinentry package as part of the core package group. pinentry-tty can be installed from AUR. Configuration is simple: in ~/.bashrc put "export GPG_TTY=$(tty)", and in ~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf put "pinentry-program /usr/bin/pinentry-curses", then restart the agent: "echo RELOADAGENT | gpg-connect-agent". It works on my system. I also tried pinentry-tty, but it did not work for me, as the password prompt appears, but then crashes.

Comment: The crash probably occurs as mutt handles console I/O on some way not compatible to pinentry-tty. I think mutt uses (n)curses, anyway.

Comment: In addition to my first comment: the 'pinentry-tty' and 'pinentry-curses' binaries are now included in the pinentry package from the core package repository in Archlinux. No other package is needed.

Comment: This is very helpful for anyone who needs to use Mutt via ssh.  The recommendations in the answer from @JensErat and the comment from Philipp work whether or not the crypt_use_gpgme variable is set to "yes" in the .muttrc file (as mentioned in the question).